# Smartsheet API not letting me save

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am attempting to update a sheet that we use for our roster in smartsheet. I am clearing out all the rows and then adding them back based on out database.

Here is what I have as far as the code goes:

```
Sheet roster = ssc.SheetResources.GetSheet(SomeSheeNumberGoesHere, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
Dictionary<string, long> columnMap = new Dictionary<string, long>();
foreach (Column column in roster.Columns)
    columnMap.Add(column.Title, (long)column.Id);
roster.Rows.Clear();
foreach (EmployeeData emp in oEmploys)
{
    var newCells = new List<Cell>();
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["WFM_ID"], Value = emp.WFM_ID });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["Email"], Value = emp.Email });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["Employee"], Value = emp.Employee });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["Supervisor"], Value = emp.Supervisor });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["FirstName"], Value = emp.FirstName });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["LastName"], Value = emp.LastName });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["Tier"], Value = emp.Tier });
    newCells.Add(new Cell() { ColumnId = columnMap["Title"], Value = emp.Title });
    Row trow = new Row() { 
        Cells = newCells
    };
    roster.Rows.Add(trow);
}
ssc.SheetResources.UpdateSheet(roster);
```

on that last line, I get the following error:

> Smartsheet.Api.InvalidRequestException: 'The attribute(s) sheet.dependenciesEnabled, sheet.permalink, sheet.accessLevel, sheet.version, sheet.rows[], sheet.effectiveAttachmentOptions[], sheet.createdAt, sheet.totalRowCount, sheet.modifiedAt, sheet.columns[], sheet.hasSummaryFields, sheet.resourceManagementEnabled, sheet.ganttEnabled, sheet.userPermissions are not allowed for this operation.'

I can't find anywhere on  any of the forums on how to fix this. any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, intuitively, it seems like you'd want to use the **Update Sheet** operation to add rows to a sheet, that's not how the Smartsheet API works. To add rows to a sheet, you'll need to use the **Add Rows** operation.

If I understand correctly, your objective is to:

1. Delete all rows from the specified sheet.
2. Add new rows to the specified sheet (using employee data from a database).

The code sample below shows how to achieve this, using 4 basic steps:

1. Get sheet (by using the **Get Sheet** operation) and build column map.
2. Delete all rows from sheet (by using the **Delete Rows** operation).
3. Create Array of the rows to be added to the sheet.
4. Add rows to the sheet (by using the **Add Rows** operation).

Please note -- the sheet I'm testing with has only 3 columns: `Name`, `Email`, and `Phone` -- and the code sample below constructs test data accordingly. You can omit the portion of code that's preceded with the comment `// create (fake) Employee data...` (since your data is coming from a database) and will need to edit the portion of code that's creating the `Cell` objects (so that it accurately reflects the structure of your sheet and the cells you want to populate). You'll also need to update the value of the `sheetId` property to be your sheet's ID.

```
var sheetId = 1303196942526340;

// 1- get sheet and build column map
Sheet roster = ssc.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
Dictionary<string, long> columnMap = new Dictionary<string, long>();
foreach (Column column in roster.Columns) {
    columnMap.Add(column.Title, (long)column.Id);
}

// 2- delete all rows from sheet
long [] rowIds = new long[roster.Rows.Count];
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < roster.Rows.Count; ctr++) {
    rowIds[ctr] = (long)roster.Rows[ctr].Id;
}
ssc.SheetResources.RowResources.DeleteRows(sheetId, rowIds, true);

// create (fake) Employee data (to mimic the data that's you'll be getting from a database)
EmployeeData [] oEmploys = new EmployeeData[2];
EmployeeData employee1 = new EmployeeData();
employee1.SetInfo("John Doe", "johndoe@test.com", "555-111-2222");
EmployeeData employee2 = new EmployeeData();
employee2.SetInfo("Jane Doe", "janedoe@test.com", "555-333-4444");
oEmploys[0] = employee1;
oEmploys[1]= employee2;

// 3- create Array of the rows to be added to the sheet
Row [] rowsToAdd = new Row[oEmploys.Count()];
int i = 0;
foreach (EmployeeData emp in oEmploys)
{
    Cell[] newCells = new Cell[] {
        new Cell { ColumnId = columnMap["Name"], Value = emp.name },
        new Cell { ColumnId = columnMap["Email"], Value = emp.email },
        new Cell { ColumnId = columnMap["Phone"], Value = emp.phone }
    };

    Row trow = new Row() { 
        Cells = newCells,
        ToBottom = true
    };

    // add row to rowsToAdd[]
    rowsToAdd[i] = trow;
    i += 1;
}

// 4- add rows to the sheet
ssc.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(sheetId, rowsToAdd);
```

Comment: After I posted this I as reading other unrelated articles and it was pretty close to what you put here except I didn't do the  ToBottom = true which was causing an error. Thank you for your help. It is greatly appreciated